# Service Worker (invisible) error in Chrome DevTools console

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, service-worker

I am working with service workers and I have a situation where under Applications in my Chrome DevTools I see an indication that there are errors with my service worker however everything works fine and the console does not display any errors. Furthermore, I cannot click on the error indicator. Please see the attachment.

Can someone let me know what that error indicator is? How to display it? Why is it there?

[image]

Comment: clicking it doesn't show a list? what about the network tab maybe it's failed requests?

Comment: clicking on it shows the console but there are no errors in there whatsoever.

Comment: It happened to me also many times. But I've realised that closing the developer tools and reopening again the Application tab makes the error disappear. So not sure if it's really an error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone having issues with service worker invisible errors, in the developer console (chrome) there is an option "Selected context only". When this option is checked only some errors will be visible in the console. Uncheck it to see all errors from the service worker.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this sort of thing for failed network requests (i.e. due to the device being offline). It doesn't necessarily indicate that there is an issue with your service worker itself.

In particular, if your service worker handles failed network requests by falling back to a cached response, then seeing what you're seeing is not likely to indicate a user-visible issue.

Comment: it'd be really great to see what's going on behind the scenes. I'd expect that link like message to be clickable and to show some further information.

Comment: Understood. https://crbug.com/new is the preferred way of making sure that request is seen by the right folks.

Comment: added an issue to chrome bug tracker: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=995702